# How to use Python to add key positions for modal operations?

Tags: python

[image]

I already know how to add regular keymaps in Python, but I don't know how to write keymaps for modal operations. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much. I know I can manually specify it in my preferences, but I would like to add the corresponding operation method for my plugin using Python,Knife Tool Modal Map > Add > Cancel "Q"

```
mouse_keymap = []

def kk_register_keymap_keys():
kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
if kc:        
    km_mesh = kc.keymaps.new(name="Mesh", space_type='EMPTY')#网格模式

    kmi = km_mesh.keymap_items.new("object.context_select", 'LEFTMOUSE', 'DOUBLE_CLICK', shift=True)
    kmi.properties.mode = 'ADD'
    mouse_keymap.append((km_mesh, kmi))

    kmi = km_mesh.keymap_items.new("object.context_select", 'LEFTMOUSE', 'DOUBLE_CLICK')
    kmi.properties.mode = 'SET'
    mouse_keymap.append((km_mesh, kmi))
    kmi_cse = km_mesh.keymap_items.new('object.connect_tool', 'E', 'PRESS', ctrl=True,shift=True)
    kmi_ac = km_mesh.keymap_items.new('wm.tool_set_by_id', 'C', 'PRESS', alt=True)
    kmi_ac.properties.name = 'builtin.knife'
    kmi_lc = km_mesh.keymap_items.new(ToggleLoopcutOperator.bl_idname, 'LEFT_CTRL', 'PRESS')
    kmi_qmesh = km_mesh.keymap_items.new('wm.tool_set_by_id', 'Q','PRESS')
    kmi_qmesh.properties.name = 'builtin.select_box'
    kmi_acg = km_mesh.keymap_items.new('mesh.set_edge_flow', 'ACCENT_GRAVE', 'PRESS')
    kmi_see = km_mesh.keymap_items.new('mesh.extrude_region_shrink_fatten', 'E', 'PRESS',shift=True)
    mouse_keymap.extend([(km_mesh, kmi_lc),(km_mesh, kmi_cse), (km_mesh, kmi_ac), (km_mesh, kmi_qmesh), (km_mesh, kmi_acg), (km_mesh, kmi_see)])

def kk_unregister_keymap_keys():
for km, kmi in mouse_keymap:
    km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
mouse_keymap.clear()
```

Comment: You can't, it stopped being supported https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/e8dd96516c60c4c43c8eb217f2c2cc61761cd0a0 https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-do-i-add-a-modal-key-layout-for-an-existing-operator/16778 https://devtalk.blender.org/t/what-is-the-proper-way-to-disable-keymap-items-in-the-user-keyconfig-via-addon/6451/5 https://devtalk.blender.org/t/modal-addon-keymaps/17444/3

Comment: oh no !But thank you for telling me the truth